# How to monkey patch a rake task shipped with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I just found a bug in one of the rake tasks shipped with Rails. Is there a way to monkey patch a rake task?

Comment: have you thought of submitting the bug to lighthouse?

Comment: Yes, I will. In next few days... :-)

Comment: Done. Take a look at https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4141

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

You can do something like this:

```
Rake::Task['doc:app'].clear
```

and then define your own task

```
namespace :doc do
  task :app do
    # work your magic
  end
end
```